# How can I view tables as query text in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created a table in SQL Server 2008 in designer mode. Now I would like to show this table as query statement (create table ..)

Is there an option that shows the table as query mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the table in the Object Browser, and select:

```
Script Table as -> CREATE To -> New Query Editor Window
```

Comment: You were 5s quicker than me!

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server Management Studio, right-click on the table name and Script as CREATE TABLE